# Breadcrumb Language

Tags: language, breadcrumb

I have created a custom page layout, with its own custom content type. It seems that the breadcrumb in SharePoint inherits the page 'Title' field for the breadcrumb. However, changing the language and editing the field changes it for both languages.

MUI feature is installed and activated.

My question is how do I get the breadcrumb to change language when changing language in SharePoint.

Note: it is a publishing site

Comment: Tried specifying the Title separately for both variations of the page?

Comment: when clicking on the link 'Variation labels' SharePoint dies out and give me an error saying "List 'Étiquettes de variantes' does not exist at site with URL ". I have also tried changing it when the page is being displayed french and that did not work either